# How to sum a column based on the value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

[image: Project Table]

In the table provided I am trying to sum the values in the "2012" Column but only if the value in the Interview column equals Y. So the sum for 2012 should be 255 since the interview column is Y for projects 1,3,and 4.  I have tried a few different things but I am not having much luck. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to use is the sumif function.  This function takes a range of values to check for conditions, a condition and a range to sum based on the conditions.

```
SUMIF(Range,Criteria,Sum_range)

SUMIF(interviewCell,Y,2012Column)
```

<strike>If I understand your question correctly you are wanting to sum the column based on a condition.</strike>

```
if(condition, true action, false action)
```

Using an if statement we can create a condition where the sum is done only if the interview value equals y.

```
=if(interviewCell=Y,sum(2012 Column),FalseAction)
```

In this code you are comparing the interview to Y and if it is true you are returning the sum function of the 2012 column.  You can choose what action you would like preformed if it is false.  Removing this argument makes the if function return "false".

Comment: I only want to sum certain values in the column. So in the image I provided projects 1,3,and 4 are all flagged as Y for interview. I want to sum only these values in the 2012 column. The if formula you gave is giving the sum of all 5 projects from 2012.

Comment: I have updated my answer to do the above action.

Comment: Thank you! I can't believe how easy that actually was. I was making it way more complex then I needed

Comment: @LukeJonkman Would be nice you posted the actual solution instead of "thank you"...